# PDFsharp bookmarks in text

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, pdfsharp

How can I create something like bookmark but in the text? Like URL, click on this bookmark in any place in text and it redirects you to other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PdfPage class offers:

- AddDocumentLink
- AddWebLink
- AddFileLink

So with PDFsharp you'd use page.AddDocumentLink to jump to another page in the same document.