# Edit pdf bookmark urls using C#

Tags: c#, itext, bookmarks

I have a pdf file which has bookmarks to different chapters(each chapter is linked to another pdf file in seperate folder using bookmarks). clicking on each chaptername will open a new pdf in the same parent pdf file.

I need to retrieve the bookmark urls of parent pdf file and alter the URLs.I used below code to retrieve bookmark properties(Action,File,Title etc), however didn't succeed in altering the path as it is dictionary key value pair.

```
 IList<Dictionary<String, Object>> bmProperties= SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray("http://XXXX/Shared%20Documents/Chapters.pdf"),
null));

        foreach (IDictionary<String, Object> bmProperty in bmProperties)
        {

            foreach (var fileProperty in bmProperty.Keys)
            {
                if (fileProperty == "File")
                {
                  // need the edit the value of Key-"File". Will it be possible to alter the value using pdfwriter
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Which PDF manipulation library are you using?

Comment: I've updated your tags to reflect. Please remember to include all tags that are relavent to your question (as tags and **not** in the title).

Comment: Are these actual Pdf Bookmarks? Do they show up in the Bookmarks panel in Acrobat? Or are they just hyperlinks on a page? If the latter then see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8141831/231316

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in two steps.

1. Get the bookmarks from the parent PDF like in your code snippet above. Iterate over the `IList` and make any needed changes.
2. Open the parent PDF again a second time with a `PdfReader`. Then overwrite the existing bookmarks with what you updated in step 1:

> ```
> PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PARENT-PDF-FILE);
> using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, YOUR-STREAM)) {
>   stamper.Outlines = bmProperties;
> }
> ```

Note that in *step 1* you **must** take into account that some of the `bmProperty` (`IDictionary` from your code above) **values** may themselves be `Dictionary<String, Object>` objects, if your bookmarks have nested levels.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have much confidence about itextsharp about your requirement.. but there is another library PDFSharp that has some good bookmark functionality...

[PDFsharp bookmarks in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957799/pdfsharp-bookmarks-in-text)

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Bookmarks-sample.ashx

Regards.